# REQ: Merging "criminal-intent" into "law-and-order-criminal-intent" tag

Tags: support, tags

Can someone please merge https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/criminal-intent and https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law-and-order-criminal-intent ? I suppose the first one dates back to the era when long tags weren't possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were only two questions tagged [criminal-intent](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/criminal-intent).

Merging seems overkill so I've just removed them and the tag will be roomba'd in due course.

Comment: Merging would probably have been preferable still because it transfers `criminal-intent`'s tag wiki over to the other tag, which doesn't have one yet. So I merged it anyway.

Comment: Though, apparently the tag wiki wasn't copied for whatever reason. Maybe because the tag didn't have any questions anymore. Nevermind.